# html - scrollbar and modal window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have problem with scrollbar.[image]

This is OK.

[image]

But when I open modal window, which has scrollbar, last numbers will be hidden. I don´t want to have hidden last numbers, I want to have visible last numbers. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

there are three possible workarouds.
add a flag when the window is modal, when it's valorized you can:

1)enlarnge your last td or div width  (i don't know how you are doing it)

2)you can add some spacing with &nbsp

3)you can add another td or div after the last column.